# PHP why can i get 2 concurrent LOCK_EX on the same handle?

Tags: php, flock

why does this code print 3x true?

```php
<?php

$h = tmpfile();
var_dump(flock($h, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB));
var_dump(flock($h, LOCK_SH|LOCK_NB));
var_dump(flock($h, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB));
```

why doesn't the initial LOCK_EX block the 2 other requests?
3v4l: https://3v4l.org/3gTv1

fwiw trying to lock a second handle to the same file does not work:

```php
<?php

$h = tmpfile();
$h2 = fopen(stream_get_meta_data($h)['uri'], 'rb');
var_dump(flock($h, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB));
var_dump(flock($h2, LOCK_SH|LOCK_NB));
```

prints bool(true) bool(false)

Answer (score 1):

According to this note https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#78318:

> If however, you call flock on a file on which you possess the lock, it will try to change it. So: flock(LOCK_EX) followed by flock(LOCK_SH) will get you a SHARED lock, not "read-write" lock.

I suppose that the PID of process, currently owning a lock, is considered somehow in flock(). So when you call it again on the handle, on which your currently running process already has a lock, it doesn't try to re-possess lock, just changes it's mode if needed.

Seems like logical behavior, not well-documented, though.

Comment: But be aware that changing lock mode seemingly involves releasing and re-possessing a lock under the hood, which is not safe, because another process theoretically can intervene and intercept the lock.
I've made this conclusion from the php docs note, mentioned above, which states that php flock behaves similar to linux flock(), and from this article about linux flock(): https://apenwarr.ca/log/20101213